# Powershell DistinctBy Condition

Tags: powershell

How can I filter a list in PowerShell to be distinct by a *condition*?

I need to select file paths which differ as absolute paths BUT filter out duplicates by file name (regardless of where they are).

So for these file paths:

```
D:\MyFolder\MyProject.dll

D:\MyFolder\MySubfolder\MyProject.dll
```

`Get-Unique` won't work because they *are* unique. How can I select the absolute path but make it distinct by file name only?

Current script looks like this:

```
get-childitem D:\MyFolder -recurse -filter "*.dll" | Select -expand FullName
```

How can I just it to return (either) one of the above on the condition that `FileName = MyProject.dll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `sort -unique` on the property before expanding:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\MyFolder' -Recurse -Filter '*.dll' | 
  Sort-Object -Unique -Property Name | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: does property have to be replaced by the actualy property?