# How to use aggregate function MAX with SELECT *?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have this query statement:

```
$Table = Query "SELECT *, MAX([sequence]) from [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input' ORDER BY MAX([sequence])"
```

i have a table that lists a rows of cubes, with each cube repeated twice, and hence a sequence repeated twice.

for example:

[image: Table]

the reason i have a cube listed twice is because each has a different query server (2 query servers per cube).

I want to return this statement for a for loop purpose, and pass just ONE row/sequence in a certain case im doing. so i only want back 1 row of sequence 1, and 1 row of sequence 2, etc... (assuming ORDER BY here)

but i get back the following error:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Column 'application' is invalid in the select
>   list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Is $table a [pscustomobject]? You could do filtering in powershell. (sort or select unique).

Comment: @Jacob Colvin yes, I tried select -object -unique but that didnt work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630337/powershell-distinctby-condition/52630463#52630463 Try using this method. Sort by cube and then select any properties you want.

Comment: @JacobColvin I cant sort by cube because i have a for loop that already loops throw each row item to return result to cube...

Comment: You can sort by whatever you wish. But if the answer resolves it you definitely should not filter on the right. You did include the powershell tag though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're on SQL Server as it's a common error.
If you want to aggregate, you need to group by explicitely each columnyou want to show.

In your case the query should be like

```
select *, max(sequence)
from <your table>
group by <an explicit list of all columns without seqence>
order by max(sequence)
```

Comment: thanks, but I still need to order by sequence though...because as you can see i might have a case with 2, then 1, which has to be run sequentially 1, then 2

Comment: $Table = Query "select *, max(sequence) from [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input' group by application, cube_name, process_server, query_server, active". I get error: Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Column 'sequence' is invalid in the select list
because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: You can still add an order by (after the group by)